# Try-Catch-Finally Not All Code Paths Return a Value

Tags: c#, sql

The following code should in an ideal circumstance execute a scalar sql command:

```
    public object AsScalar()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCommand();
        try
        {

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            log.Error("Exception caught for command: "+_sql, exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            Done(cmd);
        }
    }
```

However I receive the following error from Visual Studio 2010:

```
not all code paths return a value
```

I thought that in a try-catch-finally it will always execute the finally statement regardless of whether an exception had been caught or not, but it seems that is not the case.

Why does adding the catch clause cause this error when try-finally works without issue?

Comment: You need to have a default return clause; the compiler recognizes that your `try` block may fail.  You don't return any value (or throw an exception) outside of that.

Comment: Neither the `finally` nor the `catch` returns anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `catch` clause, if the exception is thrown you're catching it and then it's *not* propagating out of the method... so execution will get to the end of your try/catch/finally block, reach the end of the method, and you won't be returning anything - oops!

When you only had a `try/finally` statement, you'd *either* get to the `return` statement, *or* an exception would be thrown which would be propagated out of the method - both of which are fine.

If you want to rethrow the exception, you could use:

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
    log.Error("Exception caught for command: "+_sql, exc);
    throw;
}
```

That will fix the compile-time error, as now there's no way of getting to the end of the method without returning a value or an exception being propagated. However, I'd generally discourage the "log/throw/log/throw" chain going up the stack - it's usually cleaner to *just* log at the top level, with whatever's ultimately catching the exception. If you want to add more context, you could either add it to the existing exception (there's the [`Exception.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property, although it's rarely used in my experience) or wrap this exception in another one.

Comment: First off, thanks your answer is definitely helpful and leads to a better understanding of whats going on so +1 for that. Second, what about returning a blank or null object, from the catch?

Comment: @PseudoNym01 that would compile but at runtime as Jon explains this will mean errors will be eaten, which might result in unknown / unsafe state for your application. You should handle sql exceptions properly, not just assume they can be ignored. Therefore the best thing to do here would most certainly be throwing the exception back.

Comment: My ultimate goal would be handle the exception gracefully, wouldn't rethrowing the exception cause a probable crash within the application itself?

Answer (score 2):

The `catch` block, as it is, simply logs a message. It never returns anything or throw back the exception. Therefore, a possible execution path is that an exception gets thrown, will be logged and then... nothing ever gets returned. Indeed, the `finally` block will be executed but there's no `return` statement there either.

To solve this you can either throw back the exception or return null inside the `catch` block. I should mention that throwing back should normally be the preferred solution.